# Couldnt spawn debuggee: embedded null byte error

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a Django project. When I try to debug this project via VS Code, I get the following error.

```
E+00000.046: /handling #1 request "launch" from Adapter/
             Handler 'launch_request' (file '/Users/dervisoglu/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.5.86806/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/wheels/debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/launcher/handlers.py', line 18)
             couldn't handle #1 request "launch" from Adapter:
             Couldn't spawn debuggee: embedded null byte
```

How can I sollve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. I would open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy.